# Jquery - run $.ajax() on window load

Tags: jquery, load, window

I was wondering if it is possible to use $.ajax() inside window load and get data from a php file.
If not then what alternatives do I have?

```
$(window).load(function() {
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: file.php,
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
   // to do
  }
 });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. `$(window).load` just delays the code execution until after all content on the page has finished loading, so there really isn't any reason it wouldn't work as long as your `$.ajax` call is correct. Why do you ask? Is something not working for you?

Answer (score 2):

The data seems a little incomplete, for example, do you have any issues, or how do you load jquery and your own code into the page, so I may answer the wrong question :)

First, have a look at, for a good example, http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/
Do you really want the load event, or wouldn't the ready event be better?

Second, if you don't need the DOM but just want to start the AJAX call asap don't wait for either event - just issue the call. At that point you must already have loaded jquery at least anway, so you are all set for starting an AJAX call early, page still loading or not. If you DO want to work on the DOM, still issue the AJAX call right away - and put the ready (or load) event listening into the AJAX success function.

Answer (score 0):

Sure is. It's executed once the page is loaded. A more common method is using [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) but I guess it should work anyway.